# R: integrate() function with multiple arguments

Tags: r

I have a function, for now it is a Gaussian:

```
G<-function(x, mu, s) 1/(2*s**2*pi)**0.5 * exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*s**2))
```

I want to integrate it with `mu`=50, `s`=10 using `integrate()`. E.g.

```
integrate(G(s=10,mu=50), 0, 10) 
Error in G(s = 10, mu = 50) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

The problem stems from the fact that `integrate()` expects a function with a single argument and I am giving it a function that takes 3.  I can "solve" the problem by giving `mu` and `s` defaults, but then I lose generality.  What is the best way of handling this?

*Edit* : this was marked as a duplicate.  There was no accepted answer in that question, nor is it clear to me exactly what is being asked there.  The error message that question had is different than mine.

Comment: Study `help("integrate")`, in particular the description of its arguments. `integrate(G, 0, 10, s=10, mu=50)`

Comment: Is this typically how functions are passed as arguments in R?

Comment: This is typical if you pass a function to another function and need to pass additional parameters to the former. E.g., `lapply` is set up in the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on Roland's comment.  The correct way of doing this is :

```
 integrate(G, 0, 10, s=10, mu=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
integrate(G, s = 10, mu = 50, 0, 10)
```

G is a single object in R. U try to calculate G

```
G(s=10,mu=50)
```

but defines it with 3 args

```
G<-function(x, mu, s)
```

x is missing. Don't calculate it, just push it like object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
integrate(function(x, mu=50, s=10) 1/(2*s**2*pi)**0.5 * exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*s**2)), 0, 10)
```